# My brother cannot connect to my Minecraft LAN world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have tried many times to play with my brother. We are on the same Wifi, with different accounts.

I start up Minecraft 1.7.9, create a new Survival world, click Esc->Open To Lan. It tells me the port (which seems to be a random number) in the chat.

My brother tries to connect to the world. On the Multiplayer screen it searches for the LAN world forever and it never shows up. Is it supposed to only have the port or it also need the IP like 192.168:{port} but for me I dont even have the IP.

**Notes:**

- We both use Windows 8
- Same Wifi
- Different minecraft account
- Same House
- We try switching which side hosts a Lan server, and we get a different port

Comment: Do you mind adding some proper punctuation marks to your question and make it clearer? I can't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Minecraft.net and download the server. Easy to setup (and if you can't figure it out the minecraft wiki explains things) and works better than Open To LAN.